# Problem understanding sin(x)

Tags: flash, math, trigonometry

Hey peeps,
I got this code:

```
red = red + 1;
trace("red: " + red);
trace("Math.sin(red): " + Math.sin(red));
var newRed:uint = Math.abs(Math.sin(red)) * 255;
trace("newRed: " + newRed);
```

This code outputs the following:

```
red: 256
Math.sin(red): -0.9992080341070627
newRed: 254
red: 257
Math.sin(red): -0.5733571748155426
newRed: 146
red: 258
Math.sin(red): 0.37963562682930313
newRed: 96
red: 259
Math.sin(red): 0.9835931839466808
newRed: 250
```

etc.

When I plug sin(257) into the calculator I get -0.974370064785235 but Flash is coming up with -0.5733571748155426

**Edit:-**

However when I plug sin(256) i get the same number from each. This is what confuses me.

I'm a bit confused about why this is. Please help.
Alex

Comment: See the answer by user492238. This is most likely the issue: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html#sin(). When in doubt, RTFM. :)

Comment: Also note that the formula are present at the top of that page for converting between radians and degrees.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make sure you supply the right format of input arguments. Some may expect the parameter to express the angle in radians, some in degree.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sine?section=9#Properties_relating_to_the_quadrants

According to the [Action Script reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html) the sin function expects the parameter as radian.

Comment: It should return the same value as the calculator though. I'm not using the sin for angle measuring but for interpolation in this case.

Comment: it does return the same value (within round off errors), if the same input values are provided. Radian and Degree are just 2 different representations of the same angle. See the wikipedia article above.

Comment: When I put 256 into the calculator, I get the same result as Flash. But when I put 257 it's different. Can you explain this?

Comment: which result do you get for 256? And which calculator are you using?

Comment: Windows calc: sin(256) -> 
rad: -0,99920803410706269906759056238387  
deg: -0,97029572627599647230637787403399

Comment: Ok It's once again a problem with my understanding. Thanks for hammering it home.

Answer (score 3):

Flash is using radians units, the calculator is using degree units.